# How to get the element inside an iframe element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I have a element as below inside the document, I could get the iframe element by `document.getElementById('iframe_id')`, but how to get the element inside this iframe? I tried `iframeElement.contentWindow`, and the returned `DOMWindow` has no properties. Also tried `iframeElement.docuemnt` and `iframeElement.contentDocument`, both of them are undefined.  How can I get it?  I am using the latest Chrome in my experiment.

Here is the iframe element

```
<iframe id='iframe_id'>
<html>
<body>many content here</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: are your page and the page inside the iframe from the same domain? if not, chrome will probably not give you access to the other DOM.

Comment: @Tetaxa, how to check the domain for iframe? It is very possible that they come from different domain.

Comment: the first part of the url. if the pages are on the same server you should be alright.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ONLY interrogate content in an iframe if the content has the same protocol, domain and port number as the script that interrogates it. It is called [SAME ORIGIN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

If that is the case, then this code will show the content. If not - you cannot access the iframe from a normal script in a normal html page

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2s485/) - tested in IE8, Chrome 13 and Fx6

```
function showIframeContent(id) {
  var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    try {
      var doc = (iframe.contentDocument)? iframe.contentDocument: iframe.contentWindow.document;
      alert(doc.body.innerHTML);
    }
    catch(e) {
       alert(e.message);
    }
  return false;
}


<iframe id='iframe_id1' src="javascript:parent.somehtml()"> </iframe>
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="return showIframeContent('iframe_id1')">Show</a>
<hr/>

<iframe id='iframe_id2' src="http://plungjan.name/"> </iframe>
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="return showIframeContent('iframe_id2')">Show</a>
<hr/>
```

Comment: The above sample html is just excerpt (simplified) from the Elements window at the bottom of Chrome. It shows that there is a full html inside the iframe. Do you mean this is fake in the UI?

Comment: Yes. Anyway if the page is from the same server, then my code works. Please see update about same origin

Comment: Still got `doc` undefine, very strange.

Comment: I just run your demo in my Chrome, and the the message box shows the right content in inside the html. So it could be some security issue that Chrome blocks to access the inner DOM since it comes from a different domain, as Tetaxa mentioned in the comment.

Comment: It IS a security issue if the protocol, the domain or the port is different.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with code that might tell you where the iframe content comes from - it is crude but should give you an idea

Answer (score 4):

Having:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe_id');
```

To get the content document you can use:

```
var contDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Then you can search for your element inside the iframe by id.

Comment: I suppose this should work. But I got contDoc undefined after I run your 2 statements. The returned iframe seems to be the right one.

Comment: @Thomson: It will work unless the iframe source is set to another domain.

Comment: I'm getting _Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame._ any hint?

Comment: @oneway: If you own the iframe code, check workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/750216

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access it by `document.getElementById('yourIFrame').document.getElementById('yourElement')`